# расположить два блока в одном ряду

Tags: css, html

```css
input[type=search] {
  background: #fff url('/images/sprite/search.png') no-repeat 9px center;
  padding: 9px 10px 10px 25px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10em;
  -moz-border-radius: 10em;
  border-radius: 10em;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
  float: left;
  width: 17%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  font-family: $lato;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
 input[type=search]:focus {
   border-color: #6dcff6;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
}

.destination-places-menu{
 float: right;
 width: 50%;
 margin-right: 15%;
 
}
.destination-places{
 font-family: $lato;
 font-size: $font-size-sixteen;
 color: $light-grey;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="destination-search">
 <form >
     <input placeholder="Search destination" type="search">
   </form>
 </div>
 <div class="destination-places-menu">
   <a href="#" class="destination-places">All place/</a>
   <a href="#" class="destination-places">Recomended place</a>
 </div>
```

Привет! Через раз получается расположить два блока в одной строке - и вот этот случай, как раз тогда, когда не получается. помогите, пожалуйста, застряла на этом и сойти с места не могу

Comment: у вас два блока и так в одной строке, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Оборачиваешь два блока которые должны быть в одну линию одним родительским,  и родительскому блоку присваиваешь свойство `display: flex;`  Если интересно, можешь почитать про [Flexbox](http://frontender.info/a-guide-to-flexbox/);

```css
input[type=search] {
  background: #fff url('/images/sprite/search.png') no-repeat 9px center;
  padding: 9px 10px 10px 25px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10em;
  -moz-border-radius: 10em;
  border-radius: 10em;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
  font-family: $lato;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

input[type=search]:focus {
  border-color: #6dcff6;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109, 207, 246, .5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109, 207, 246, .5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109, 207, 246, .5);
}

.destination-places-menu {
  margin-left: 15%;
}

.destination-places {
  font-family: $lato;
  font-size: $font-size-sixteen;
  color: $light-grey;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* центрирование по вертикали */
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="destination-search">
    <form>
      <input placeholder="Search destination" type="search">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="destination-places-menu">
    <a href="#" class="destination-places">All place/</a>
    <a href="#" class="destination-places">Recomended place</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а обязательно через flex ? других не бывает технологий ?

Comment: это самый простой, а вообще есть куча вариантов как центрировать элементы, те же relative - absolute, или translate X-Y

Comment: если изменить doctype на 1.1 то можно вместо flex и margin auto и прочих танцев просто поместить через тег center , это не проще ?